# Tried replacing a temp file by renaming to my original file name.. But it's not working?

Tags: java, jframe

Ok, I tried to rename my temp file to ori file name. However no matter what I tried. The temp file won't rename to my ori file name.
My code:

```
`public class delete
{
    
   public void deleteLines(String filepath,int positionofTerm,String delimeter,String removeTerm)
    {
        int position = positionofTerm - 1;
            String tempFile = "temp.txt";
            File oldFile = new File(filepath);
            File newFile = new File(tempFile);
            
            String currentLine;
            String data[];
            
            try
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(filepath);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                
                while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    data = currentLine.split(" : ");
                    if(!(data[position].equalsIgnoreCase(removeTerm)))
                    {
                        pw.println(currentLine);
                    }
                }
                
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                fr.close();
                br.close();
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
                
                oldFile.delete();
                File dump = new File(filepath);
                newFile.renameTo(dump);
                
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
    }
}`
```

When user pressed "Delete" button:

```
`delete obj1 = new delete();
        obj1.deleteLines("bookingDetails.txt", 2," : ", jTextField2.getText());`
```

bookingDetails.txt:

```
`howard : 11-1111-11-1111 : 014-222-2222 : howarde@gmail.com : 2dos : 16-May-2023 : 20-May-2023 : 3 : 206 : 208 :
emilia : 04-4444-44-4444 : 019-888-8888 : emilia@gmail.com : 2dos : 15-May-2023 : 20-May-2023 : 1 : 101 :`
```

temp.txt:

```
`emilia : 04-4444-44-4444 : 019-888-8888 : emilia@gmail.com : 2dos : 15-May-2023 : 20-May-2023 : 1 : 101 :`
```

1. Made sure that I close the files before i rename / delete it.
2. Tried debugger and it actually did loop inside the rename section.

Comment: Replace newFile.renameTo(dump) with `Files.move(newFile.toPath(), Path.of(filepath));`.  Doing so may or may not solve your problem, but if it doesn’t work, you will get an informative and useful exception.  The File class is a very old API which has some unfortunate design mistakes.  Use [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead, whenever possible.